# How to disable a node in a treelist in Ext JS 7 classic

Tags: node.js, extjs6-classic, disable, treelist, extjs7

Hi can anyone please tell me how i can disable a node in a treelist. I am using Ext JS 7 classic.

I tried a config `disabled: true` on the treelistitem something like the below code. this config is there on the treelistitem in Ext JS 7 classic docs. But it does not work. Can anyone help please.

```
{
     text: eachRevision.name,
     iconCls: 'x-fa fa-folder',
     leaf: false,
     disabled: true
}
```

Comment: I believe it was never implemented. See this forum thread https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?304714-How-disable-a-node-of-a-treelist

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'visible' instead of disabled. Set 'visible' to false on record in the node store.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for responding, i believe i am very late to thank you.